# Sending SMS to multiple recepients (Samsung vs HTC)

Tags: android, android-intent, sms

I am using the following code in Samsung that works fine for me,

```
Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO,Uri.parse("smsto:123,456"));
smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body", messageBody);
startActivity(smsIntent);
```

and the following that works fine in HTC

```
Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO,Uri.parse("smsto:123;456"));
smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body", messageBody);
startActivity(smsIntent);
```

Difference is the use of "," and ";" as a delimiter in samsung and htc respectively. Is there a generic way to do that (without using sms manager).

Any help is appreciated in advance

Comment: follow this link 
   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11700824/device-check-samsung-vs-others/11700952#11700952