# Device Check (Samsung vs Others)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-2.2-froyo

I am working on an application, where there is some code implementation difference for samsung and htc, kindly have a look at my SO question

[Sending SMS to multiple recepients (Samsung vs HTC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11687092/sending-sms-to-multiple-recepients-samsung-vs-htc)

How can I put a check for if the device is samsung or others(htc)

Comment: Check this: [Android.os.Build data examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103196/android-os-build-data-examples-please/8056925#8056925)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
String manufacturer = android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER;
```

example:

`Sony Ericsson`

`samsung`

`HTC`

Comment: be careful, since for samsung device with canogen it will still return you Samsung

Comment: Then check like this in Kotlin: Build.MANUFACTURER.equals("samsung", ignoreCase = true)

Answer (score 12):

Try this code.

```
String strManufacturer = android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER;
```

It will return name of Manufacturer. Ex Htc

```
String str = android.os.Build.MODEL;
```

It will returns name of device. Ex Htc Explorer , HTC Smith

Look at [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html) for further info.