# Is there a way to set and app icon for Samsung devices specifically?

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, samsung-galaxy, android-attributes

I noticed that the Samsung apps have a specific shape; for example, the Gallery, Camera, Phone, Messages and Internet app icons below.

[image]

Is there a way to specify an icon for Samsung devices *only*? Something similar to how the new Google Pixel uses the [`android:roundIcon`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#roundIcon) attribute in the manifest?

I tried looking for something in the [Samsung Developer documentation](http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/getting-started), but there does not seem to be anything on the topic.

The devices do have a way of recognizing the Samsung apps, considering the **Icons with backgrounds** setting [**Settings** > **Display** > **Icon backgrounds**] enables a similarly shaped background for all other apps. For example, the Google Play Store icon below.

[image]

But I am unsure if this is a publicly-available option.

---

This question would be inconsequential if Samsung adopts Android Oreo's new [adaptive icons](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive.html); but as far as I know they haven't yet.

Answer (score 9):

You can disable TouchWiz to surround your application icon in a rounded square frame by setting

```
<application>
    <meta-data android:name="com.samsung.android.icon_container.has_icon_container" android:value="true"/>
</application>
```

to your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Interesting. From what I can tell, that just tells TouchWiz not to surround the icon in a rounded circle when the option is enabled (i.e. the Google Play Store icon mentioned in my question). It still doesn't give me the ability to provide a Samsung-specific app icon though. But if Samsung recognizes this `meta-data` tag, I wonder what other tags they recognize. Would you happen to know of any others? Is there any official documentation on the subject (I couldn't find any)?

Answer (score 2):

To detected if you are running in a Samsung device is easy:

```
android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER == "samsung"
```

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11700824/device-check-samsung-vs-others)

So after you have defined that you are running in a Samsung device, you could change your app to change the app icon programatically when running in Samsung devices. But unfortunately android doesn't provide a way of doing it.

There are some work arounds to change de app icon, you can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103027/how-to-change-an-application-icon-programmatically-in-android), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22129724/change-icon-launcher-and-app-name-programmatically) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20851274/how-to-change-launcher-icon-and-its-label-from-the-application)

If you really need to change your icon, you can try the workarouds, but if is just to keep in standard with the non-standard samsung icons, them I would not do it ;)

Comment: This would work, but I was hoping for something a bit less hacky. Not to mention the fact that the `INSTALL_SHORTCUT` workaround creates a `Toast` when a new shortcut is installed/uninstalled. I think I'll keep the icon as-is, unless a better option becomes available from Samsung.